# Can I prebuild devcontainer for local vscode installation (like GitHub Codespaces prebuilds)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces

Github codespaces provides a prebuild option - [documentation link](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/prebuilding-your-codespaces/about-github-codespaces-prebuilds)

I do not use codespaces. Instead, I use VS Code locally.
I have my devcontainer setup as I like it.
It compiles and runs the way I want.
But the feature installation and other tasks are lengthy.
Can I prebuild this image just like what codespaces offers?

Comment: Also wondering the same thing. It seems like it fundamentally changes "which devcontainer features should be used" (e.g. `updateContent`, `features`, etc.) if the same prebuilds and caching aren't available to devcontainers that are available to Codespaces. 

Seems like there's no documentation anywhere on this.